# WordPress hook after adding/updating post AND after insertion of post meta?

Tags: wordpress, hook, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called "videos", which also has a few custom fields defined.  Upon creating or updating a "videos" post, I would like to run a function.

Unfortunately, this function needs the values of the post meta data for the post that I've just created, and the usual hooks (`save_post`,`publish_post`, etc.) seem to run before the post meta is inserted into the database, so it isn't available.

If I manually update the post just by clicking "Publish" without making any changes, function works properly.

**Is there a hook that fires later in the process, after all metadata has been inserted?**

Comment: why you are not using `wp_insert_post` ?? or `wp_update_post` ?

Comment: I've tried them - they also fire before the meta data is inserted into the database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an <del>undocumented</del> hook called [`updated_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/updated_%28meta_type%29_meta) that does what I need.

It will pass 4 parameters to the hooked function: the meta ID, the object ID (same as the post ID), the meta key, and the meta value.  In my hooked function I check to see if the meta key name is the field that I need the value of and, if so, it proceeds.

Here's what it looks like:

```
/**
 * Use value of post meta for something when the post 
 * meta changes
 * @param  integer $meta_id    ID of the meta data field
 * @param  integer $post_id    Post ID
 * @param  string $meta_key    Name of meta field
 * @param  string $meta_value  Value of meta field
 */
function saveYouTubeInfo($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key='', 
                                             $meta_value=''){

    // Stop if not the correct meta key
    if ( $meta_key != 'my_meta_field_name') {
        return false;
    }

    // Function code goes here.
}

add_action('updated_post_meta', 'saveYouTubeInfo', 10, 4);
```

By the way, unlike `added_post_meta`, you do not replace `post` with the post type that you are targeting.  In my case, the name of the post type is `videos`, but I still had to use `updated_post_meta` and NOT `updated_videos_meta`.

Comment: Can you guys please check this question??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072130/get-updated-value-after-post-update-custom-post-type-using-hook-in-wordpress

Comment: I encountered as similar problem and solved it using the action 'added_post_meta'.

Answer (score 1):

The reason post meta is not available yet it is because they use save_post hook to save post meta. So, you hook is not running after post meta is saved to database.

Two solutions to your problem.

1. Get the data from $_POST

add_action('save_post', 'my_function');

function my_function($post_id){

```
$postmeta = $_POST['field_name'];
```

}

2. Use a Higher priority for your hook, so it runs after post meta is saved

add_action('save_post', 'my_function', 12 , 3);

function my_function($post_id, $post, $update){

```
$postmeta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_key', true);
```

}